# What is the difference between BLDC motors and servo motors?

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, servo, electromagnetic

BLDC motors and servo motors seem physically the same. I know servo motors can do torque control, speed control, and precise position control, but BLDC motors can only do speed control.
Are there any other differences between these motors?

Comment: You might like to link to the 'servo motors' you mean. As you see, your respondants have different ideas of what they are to you.

Answer (score 2):

BLDC is a type of motor, it's a three phase synchronous motor with an electronic three phase inverter used as driver.

Servo is a way to use a motor, with a controller that takes angle feedback and drives the motor so the output shaft rotates to the required angle, which compensates applied torque. There are also linear servos that take position feedback and drive a motor to move an actuator to the desired position.

In theory, a servo can use any type of motor or actuator: brushed, brushless, stepper, hydraulic, compressed air or more exotic stuff like piezo etc. The defining characteristic of a servo is feedback taken on absolute angle or position. That doesn't depend on the type of motor, it's about the feedback sensor and controller.

For most types of motor, the controller can sense and set torque (via current). It can also sense and set rotational speed, that requires a rpm or angle sensor for some types of motor, but some brushless motors can work without it, in this case the controller senses motor current to know about rotational speed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, they are very different devices.

**Servo Motors**

Most servos are rotary actuators although other types are available. Linear actuators are sometimes used, although it is more common to use a rotary actuator with a bellcrank and pushrod.

A typical servo consists of a small electric motor driving a train of reduction gears. A potentiometer is connected to the output shaft. Some simple electronics provide a closed-loop controlled servomechanism, usially through a PID Controller.

[image: Servo Control Loop]

Given that servos have all the required components for the closed loop control built within its case, they only have 3 wires: VCC, GND and Signal. This is shown on the following image:

[image]

GND and VCC are the supply pins, and the signal pin will recieve a PWM signal where the duty cycle directly correlates to a motor shaft angle.

[image]

It's important to notice that servos have in built mechanical limits so that the rotation is mechanically limited. This serves the purpose of protecting the potentiometer from exceding its mechanical limits.

**BLDC Motors**

Brushless motors can be constructed in several different physical configurations. In the conventional inrunner configuration, the permanent magnets are part of the rotor. Three stator windings surround the rotor.

There are two common electrical winding configurations; the delta configuration connects three windings to each other in a triangle-like circuit, and power is applied at each of the connections.

[image]

If we apply the appropriate current, the coil will generate a magnetic field that will attract the rotors permanent magnet. If each coil is activated  one after another the rotor will keep rotating because of the force interaction between permanent magnets and the electromagnet.

So there are three inputs for a BLDC Motor, which are controlled by an ESC Motor Controller. ESC stands for Electronic Speed Control, and it manages to control the BLDC Motor by switching the motor inputs very fast on a defined sequence. Below is a gif with a visual representation of the controller working.

[image]

This is a way more extense topic for a post, so below I'll list some web pages that I think can be useful.

- [Servomotors Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ditS0a28Sko)
- [Some Servo info](https://howtomechatronics.com/how-it-works/how-servo-motors-work-how-to-control-servos-using-arduino/)
- [BLDC Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yiD5nCfmbV0)
- [Some BLDC Motors and ESC info](https://howtomechatronics.com/how-it-works/how-brushless-motor-and-esc-work/)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I was actually talking about industrial servo motors(BLAC).

Comment: I am inclined to think they work the same as regular servos, just with a bigger DC Motor and a stronger gearbox